# How to export a buffer I made in Google Earth Engine to a .KML file that I can open in the Google Earth desktop app

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, buffer, kml, feature-collection

I learned how to create a buffer around a polygon here...

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-feature-buffer

...and I would like to export the resulting buffer to a .KML file to load it into the Google Earth app and use it with some other polygons that I made there. How do I export that buffer to .KML?

Answer (score 0):

Since the buffer is vector data (a "feature collection" or "table" in Earth Engine terminology), you can use Export.table.toDrive to export it to KML (and other formats).

See the documentation at:
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/export-table-todrive

Answer (score 0):

I think that one can not simply Export (To Drive) a buffer object.
I tried it and failed.

The way I could export a buffer object as is explained [here](https://gisgeeks.com/how-to-create-a-pointpolygon-features-in-earth-engine/), is to :

1. Save it as a Feature.
2. Add this feature to a featureCollection.

This way, I could export the resulted featureCollection as a KML file to my Drive.